# How to pass multiple column names as input to group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to R and dplyr package. I am trying to pass a variable to dplyr **group_by**, which we can vary/change.
for instance when working with flights dataset, I can get counts of rows by any column (or multiple columns) using the code below:

```
library(nycflights13)
flights %>% group_by(origin) %>% tally()
flights %>% group_by(carrier) %>% tally()
flights %>% group_by(origin,carrier) %>% tally()
```

but if I want to pass the name of the columns used, to **group_by** as a variable, then it does not work when using multiple column names.

```
group="carrier"
flights %>% group_by_(group) %>% tally()

group="origin"
flights %>% group_by_(group) %>% tally()

group=c("origin","carrier") #This does not work
flights %>% group_by_(group) %>% tally()
```

I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've almost got it, you just need to use the `.dots` argument to pass in your grouping variables.

```
group <- c("origin","carrier") 

flights %>% 
  group_by_(.dots = group) %>% 
  tally()
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Can you please help me understand what does .dots argument do.

Comment: You use the `.dots` argument for programming with `dplyr`, it enables you to pass the what you want to do, into the `dplyr` SE functions programatically.  You should read the dplyr vignette on NSE for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Update: The `.dots` argument of `group_by()` is deprecated as of dplyr 1.0.0. Instead you can use the big bank operator `!!!` as in `group_by(!!!groups)`.

Comment: You might need 'syms' if using the triple bang. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61180201/triple-exclamation-marks-on-r